# Removing no data values from multiple raster files in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, nodata

I have 180 raster files, which have values in the range of 100 - 900. However, there are no data values in each file designated as 32766. Sometimes, it varies around 32700. I want to write a code that says remove the values that are greater than 30000 and save the file. With the help of GIS StackExchange, I was able to figure out how to save files. But, I want to know how to remove values for all raster files at once.

````
myDir = 'E:/'
layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
for layer in layers:
   extent = layer.extent()
   width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
   renderer = layer.renderer()
   provider=layer.dataProvider()
   crs = layer.crs().toWkt() 
   pipe.set(provider.clone())
   pipe.set(renderer.clone())
   file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(myDir + layer.name() + ".tif")
   file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                           width,
                           height,
                           extent,
                           layer.crs())```
````

Comment: What do you want to do with pixel values greater than 30000. Do you want to convert those values to some other values or what is your requirement?

Comment: I want to remove those values and save the raster.

Comment: Do you want to make them as No-Data or NaN values?

Comment: I don't want to see those values in the legend. I think NaN would be fine.